# How to get particular view id if two layout have same view id?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts in same project which content `TextView` having same id. I want to access text view id of particular layout. how to get it?

EX.

### how to access TextView of `Layout1.xml` ?

layout1 XML File:

```
   <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TopPanel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/header" 
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:id="@+id/title1" 
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:text="@string/AllMessages" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

layout2 XML File:

```
    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/flayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/header" 
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:id="@+id/title1" 
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:text="@string/AllMessages" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
     </FrameLayout>
```

---

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
  View vw =findViewById(R.layout.layout1);
  TextView tvBannerText =(TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.title1);
      tvBannerText.setTextColor(bannerTextColor);
      tvBannerText.invalidate();
```

Comment: which is parent Layout here...? whats the need of it.. why don't you just change the ID..

Comment: Thanks for reply..change the ID is last option..but i want do this without changing Id. i use layout1.xml as parent layout. but when i o open XML Declaration of "layout1-->txt" it show me on  layout2.xml--> txt

Comment: Try finding the ID from its parent view. If you use parent view, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

then you can do this..

```
TextView t1 = layout1.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

Layout l2 = layout1.findViewById(R.Layout.layout2);

TextView t1 = l2.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
```

Comment: I trying using below code still not working 
view v= findVieById(R.layout.layout1);   
TextView t1 =findViewById v.(R.id.yourTextView);